# set value in javascript from a jsf value

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, jqplot

In this javascript function I am trying to set max from the backingbean's max value. This is using jsf.

Using the value as I do. Will result in the chart being empty. So I assume Max is null/0. Instead of the expected value of 6100.

```
max: #{teamChart.maxResult}
```

Edit: Added the complete code for the Chart. Note that setting max inside the barChart will not give the correct functionality.

```
<p:commandButton value="Visa diagram" update="chart" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />  
            <p:dialog header="Selected Values" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg"> 
                <p:barChart id="chart" value="#{teamChart.CreateChart(serviceTeam.teamLists)}" 
                rendered="#{not empty serviceTeam.teamLists}" legendPosition="ne"  
                title="Lagresultat" animate="true" zoom="true" min="0" max="#{teamChart.maxResult}" xaxisLabel="År och vecka" 
                style="height:500px;width:900px;" extender="ext">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  function ext(){
                    this.cfg.legend = {
                       show:true,
                       placement: 'outsideGrid'
                    };
                    this.cfg.axes.yaxis = {
                                tickInterval: 500,
                                markSize: 40,
                                max: #{teamChart.maxResult},
                                min: 0,
                                tickOptions: { 
                                       formatString: '%d' 
                                   }


                    };
                  }
                </script>

                </p:barChart>
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: If your value #{teamChart.maxResult} don't change, so it will work like you mention.
If not try to render the javascript to refresh this value.

Comment: How could I render it when it's inside the chart?